# Django and Ajax. js not running

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I hope anyone can help me with my code. I have here this html that was a js function with the goal that, whenever someone changes the "filament" option, it will change the "colors" available options available in the select:

```
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="max-width: 1000px;">
         
                {% csrf_token %}
                
                {{ form.as_p }}

                {% for message in messages %}

                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>

                    {{ message }}

                </div>
                {% endfor %}

            <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
            <div class="illustration">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" name="printingfile"/ style="font-size: medium;">

                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="=filament">

                    <option value="1">PLA</option>
                    <option value="2">ABS</option></select>

                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="=color"></select>
                    
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button></div>

            </div>
          
        </form>
    </section>
    <div></div>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/Animated-Text-Background.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/Cookie-bar-footer-popup.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    {% block javascript %}
    <script>  //updating the colors available

        $("#filament").change(function () {
            var filament = $(this).val();
            var color = $('#color');
            console.log(filament);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/get_colors/',
                data: {
                'filament': filament
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                color.empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++) {
                    color.append('<option value=' + data[i].name + '>' + data[i].name + '</option>');
                }
                }
            });
            });                 

                </script>
                {% endblock javascript %}
</body>

</html>
```

This calls a view in Django. I know that the problem is here because I tried to use console.log and got 0 results, so probably there is nothing wrong (for now) in the Python code. Anyone could help me? Stuck here for hours and any tip would be really helpfull!

Comment: `data.lenght` should be `data.length` . Also , check your browser console if there are any other errors .

Comment: Also , your id is `id="=filament"` but you are targetting `$("#filament")..` change that as well.

Comment: Swadi thanks for you input but still everything the same...

Comment: Did you check your browser console are there any errors ?

Comment: Just found out that whenever I try to run $("#filament").val() or $("filament").val() in the browser console it returns undefined for some reason...Also, really thanks for your time.

Comment: Just found the problem! I was naming it "=filament" instead of "filament". Probably just wrote it the wrong way. Still, really thanks!